# Why redux state changing another state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

who can explain why in redux store articles (array) state devastates when i am changing another state (e.g. language)
here is 2 screenshots about it.
[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wph3h.png)

[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmRB8.png)

actions/language

```
    import { SWITCH_LANG } from '../types';

// switch Language
export const setlocale = (lang) => (dispatch) => {
    localStorage.devsLang = lang;
    dispatch(setLocaleDispatch(lang))
}

export const setLocaleDispatch = (lang) => ({
    type: SWITCH_LANG,
    lang
})
```

reducer/language

```
import { SWITCH_LANG } from '../types';

export default function locale(state = { lang: "en" }, action = {}) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SWITCH_LANG:
            return { lang: action.lang }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

[one more screenshot from redux-logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBfeK.png)

Comment: Pleae add minimal code. This will not get you answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite your state. You need to copy your existing state and add your new values. Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) as below:

```
Object.assign({}, state, { lang: action.lang } )
```

More info [here](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html)

Comment: which one ? article reducer ?

Comment: Yes, article reducer.

Answer (score 0):

reducer/article

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { ADD_NEW_ARTICLE, GET_ALL_ARTICLES, GET_ONE_ARTICLE } from '../types';

export default function article(state = {}, action = {}) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_NEW_ARTICLE:
            return action.article
        case GET_ALL_ARTICLES:
            return action.articles
        case GET_ONE_ARTICLE:
            return action.oneArticle
        default:
            return {};
    }
}

export const articlesHashSelector = state => state.article;

export const articlesSelector = createSelector(
    articlesHashSelector,
    hash => Object.values(hash)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the **redux-logger** screenshot

i can tell that you return an **Array** of articles, check the payload of **GET_ALL_ARTICLES** action

```
case GET_ALL_ARTICLES: 
   return action.articles
```

So basically your are mutating the article state. from object to array